# ¿Qué significa el $ delante de una cadena?

Tags: c#, string

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y me pasaron un fichero en C# con un código parecido a lo que tenía que hacer. Investigándolo me encontré con esto:

```
valorOpcion1 = "valor_que_viene_de_un_lado";
valorOpcion2 = "valor_que_viene_de_otro_lado";

var miLista = new List<string>
    {
        $"opcion1:{valorOpcion1}",
        $"opcion1:{valorOpcion2}"
    };
```

Que lo que hace es definir e inicializar una lista de cadenas con dos valores por defecto. Mi duda viene con el `$` que tienen esas cadenas, que no sé lo que es.

¿Qué es lo que hace poner el símbolo de dólar (`$`) delante de una cadena? ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre, por ejemplo, `"hola"` y `$"hola"`?

Comment: Que pregunta tan interesante. Me estoy enterando de que las cadenas interpoladas existen gracias a esto. +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quiere decir que es una cadena interpolada.

La interpolación de cadenas significa que puedes utilizar dentro de la misma variables definidas con anterioridad en tu código, y el compilador JIT se encargara de reemplazar las mismas por los valores respectivos, en tiempo de ejecución.

En tu ejemplo, cada una de las opciones va a tener como valor:

```
opcion1:valor_que_viene_de_un_lado
opcion1:valor_que_viene_de_otro_lado
```

La interpolación te permite hacer llamas a funciones dentro de la cadena, por ejemplo:

```
$"La hora actual es: {DateTime.Now:d}"
```

Y hasta inclusive podes usar un operador ternario adentro, para hacer un analisis rapido:

```
int i = 1;
string s = $"{(i==1?"si":"no")}";
```

La documentacion completa esta [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Por completar,esta sintaxis está disponible a partir de la especificacion 6 de C#

Answer (score 9):

En `C#` existen dos tipos de símbolos para darle formato a una cadena de `strings` de manera directa.

> `$` : [Cadenas Interpoladas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated): Una cadena interpolada es una cadena
>   que contiene expresiones interpoladas. Cuando una cadena interpolada
>   se resuelve en una cadena de resultado, los elementos con expresiones
>   interpoladas se reemplazan por las representaciones de cadena de los
>   resultados de la expresión. Esta característica está disponible en C#
>   6 y versiones posteriores del lenguaje.

Antes se utilizaba el formato [Compuesto de cadenas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting), haciendolo que utilizara argumentos no identificables y haciendo el proceso de darle formato a una cadena mas tedioso.

Vamos a utilizar la siguiente clase de ejemplo:

```
public class Persona {
   public string Nombre { get; private set; } = "Alvaro Montoro";
   public int Edad { get; private set; } = 20;
}
```

Utilizando el `Formato Compuesto`, para formar una cadena con los valores de persona tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Persona persona = new Persona();
string datos = string.Format("Nombre: {0} y Edad: {1} ", persona.Nombre, persona.Edad);
```

Si te fijas, el `Formato Compuesto` es guiado por indices, lo que no te da claridad de que valor esta siendo utilizado si no conoces el orden. Por lo que utilizando el formato de `Cadena Interpolada`, el formato el directo y ya conoces la propiedad asignada:

```
Persona persona = new Persona();
string datos = $"Nombre: {persona.Nombre} y Edad: {persona.Edad}";
```

> @ : [Identificador Textual con orientación a las cadenas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim): Este
>   identificador en pocas palabras, se utiliza para insertar símbolos a
>   una cadena, que no acepta caracteres especiales.

Por ejemplo, si quiero imprimir comillas en un `string`, debo insertar el simbolo `\` de por medio, lo que quiere decir, que el `\` no formara parte del resultado. Si quiero hacer que el simbolo `\` sea parte del resultado, debo utilizar el `Identificador textual`:

```
string sin_identificador = "Hola, \"StackOverflow\"";
string con_identificador = @"Hola, \""StackOverflow\""";

Console.WriteLine(sin_identificador); // Imprime Hola, "StackOverflow"
Console.WriteLine(con_identificador); // Imprime Hola, \"StackOverflow\"
```

Puedes ver mas ejemplos en la documentacion oficial adjunta.

Answer (score 5):

**¿Que es?**

`$` es un atajo para `String.Format` y se usa con interpolaciones de strings.

---

Usándolo en el string `"hola"` no modificaría nada, al igual que si usaras `String.Format("hola")`. Ahora bien en el caso que muestras en tu código:

```
$"opcion1:{valorOpcion1}",
$"opcion1:{valorOpcion2}"
```

Lo que hace es poner los valores de `valorOpcion1` y `valorOpcion2`, dentro del string.