# Almacenar valores de una query en una variable

Tags: c#

Estoy aplicando la siguiente consulta para obtener el valor de un campo existente en una tabla y capturarlo en una variable.

```
var captbarras = TextBoxLeerSerial.Text;
            string sqli = "SELECT codigobarras from articulo WHERE codigobarras='captbarras'";
            var obtenerarticulos = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sqli).FirstOrDefault();

            if (obtenerarticulos == TextBoxLeerSerial.Text)
           {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
                "alert",
                "alert('No se ha podido actualizar el codigo de barras, este codigo ya se utiliza');window.location ='/Aspx/Compras/CargarSeriales.aspx';",
                true);
            }
```

lo que requiero hacer es obtener el valor que existe en campo que selecciono y obtenerlo en la variable `obtenerarticulos`mi gran inconveniente es que no me captura ningún valor y el valor que digito en el textbox`TextBoxLeerSerial` si existe.

El tipo de dato del campo `codigobarras` en la DB es varchar

y en caso de que no exista ese valor, aplique para el else...

Comment: no leiste nunca sobre concatenar strings no? o como agregar una variable dentro d eun string? mira esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171393/324.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, cuando intento concatenarlo me toma el valor que digito en el textbox como si fuera una columna

Comment: mmm.. lo que esta a la derecha del = es el valor que estas buscando en la columna. Que queres decir?

Comment: lo que esta a la derecho del = es una variable `captbarras` que recibe el valor digitado en el textbox, lo que exactamente requiero es que busque en la base de datos exactamente en el campo codigobarras el articulo que tenga ese codigo que haya digitado en el textbox y en caso de que ese valor exista lo almacene en  `obtenerarticulos`

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir. Lee sobre concatenacion de variables. Asi no se hace en C#. por eso te pase un link con una de las formas de hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que asignar el parametro al SELECT para que aplique el fitro, ya que actualmente solo buscas los codigo que tienen

```
string sqli = "SELECT COUNT(*) from articulo WHERE codigobarras= @codigo";
var cantidad = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqli, new SqlParameter("@codigo", captbarras)).FirstOrDefault();

if(cantidad > 0) {

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
            "alert",
            "alert('No se ha podido actualizar el codigo de barras, este codigo ya se utiliza');window.location ='/Aspx/Compras/CargarSeriales.aspx';",
            true);
}
```

Presta atencio a como se usa el

```
new SqlParameter("@codigo", captbarras)
```

cuando ejecuta el sql query

Si quiere conocer si el codigo ya se esta utilizando recupera la cantidad de registros segun el filtro y no el codigo como string porque esto no indicara si existe o no, bueno salvo que valides que retorne un NULL

[Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)