# De Varchar a Date

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Se que han posteado preguntas similares a la mía pero realmente las he probado y no me funcionaron... Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio y Tengo estas lineas de código que lo que hacen es actualizar algunos datos de la tabla datosseguro pero al momento de cambiarle el año a las 3 columnas que tengo me sale el error "Conversion failed when converting date from chaacter String... 
lo raro es que tengo otra tabla de agregar usuario en donde tambien manejo fechas y al momento de agregar NO ME SUELTA ESE ERROR... por ende busco la manera de cambair el string a date... dejo las lineas de codigo:

```
        DateTime datetime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(NIVigencia.Text);
        DateTime datetime2 = Convert.ToDateTime(NFVigencia.Text);
        DateTime datetime3 = Convert.ToDateTime(fechahoy.Text);

        String ActualizarDS1 = "Update DATOSSEGURO SET Poliza = '" + NuevaPoliza.Text + "', Aseguradora = '" + Naseguradora.Text + "', FechaColozacion = '" + datetime3 + "', InitVigencia = '" + datetime1+ "', FinVigencia = '" + datetime2+ "' WHERE Poliza = " + TBPoliza.Text;
        SqlCommand actualizar = new SqlCommand();
        actualizar.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
        actualizar.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        actualizar.CommandText = ActualizarDS1;
        try
        {
            actualizar.ExecuteNonQuery();
            actualizar.Dispose();
            actualizar = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Nueva Poliza agregada con exito", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR al actualizar datosseguro :" + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Esto es un error tremendo. Deja tu consulta abierta a inyección de SQL y eso es un gran problema (Cualquiera podría tomar control de tu servidor). Para prevenir eso, siempre debes de utilizar parámetros a la hora de ejecutar código de SQL. Ejemplos aquí https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sobre tu pregunta: primero si se trata de fechas comienza por cambiar tus cajas de texto por el control de fechas (datetimepicker) que para eso está :).

Por otro lado sea que cambies el control o no, dale formato a tus fechas, el error se genera porque sql no reconoce el formato de la fecha que le estás enviando, puede ser por ejemplo que esté en inglés (02/20/2019) y tu se lo envíes en español (20/02/2019) o viceversa, para evitar esto usa el formato yyyyMMdd, y usa [interpolación de cadenas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171393/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-delante-de-una-cadena) para que tu código sea mas legible

```
string ActualizarDS1 = $"Update DATOSSEGURO SET Poliza = '{NuevaPoliza.Tex}', Aseguradora = '{Naseguradora.Text}', FechaColozacion = '{datetime1.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}', InitVigencia = '{datetime2.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}', FinVigencia = '{datetime3.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}' WHERE Poliza ={TBPoliza.Text}";
```

Para el formato de fechas, como ves en el código puedes usar el método datetime1.ToString("yyyyMMdd") o bien aprovechando la interpolación puedes darle el formato así {datetime1.Date:yyyyMMdd}

Ahora bien las instrucciones de sql es mejor las ejecutes por procedimientos alamcenados como te recomienda edgar, principalmente para que evites el [sql injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: `-->` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279243/de-varchar-a-date#comment513625_279243 La interpolación de cadenas no evita la inyección SQL

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!, por otra parte iba a poner el  datetimepicker pero como aumento una hora al momento de llamarlo no lo vi necesario. me sirvio mucho tu ayuda, ¡Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Hola @Phi si te fijas bien en mi comentario dije "usa interpolación de cadenas para que tu código sea mas legible" no para evitar sql injection, si vuleves a fijarte al final de mi comentario dije que usara procedimientos almacenados para evitar sqlinjection ;)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar un SP y mandas como parametro la fecha y le haces un CAST algo como esto.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[St_UpdDatosSeguro]
@NuevaPoliza NVARCHAR(50),
@Aseguradora NVARCHAR(50),
@FechaColozacion NVARCHAR(50),
@InitVigencia NVARCHAR(50),
@FinVigencia NVARCHAR(50),
@Poliza NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
Update DATOSSEGURO SET Poliza = @NuevaPoliza, Aseguradora = @Aseguradora, FechaColozacion = CAST(@FechaColozacion AS date), InitVigencia = CAST(@InitVigencia AS date), FinVigencia = CAST(@FinVigencia AS date)
 WHERE Poliza = @Poliza;
END
```

Y tu string quedaria de este modo

```
String ActualizarDS1 = "EXEC  [dbo].[St_UpdDatosSeguro] '" + NuevaPoliza.Text + "','" + Naseguradora.Text + "', '" + datetime3 + "','" + datetime1+ "', '" + datetime2+ "' ," +"'+ TBPoliza.Text"';
```

Comment: `-->` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279243/de-varchar-a-date#comment513625_279243